# What's the point of the thresholds in Punycode/Bitstring?

Tags: number-theory, numeral-representations

I've just read the Punycode spec in [RFC 3492](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3492), as well as descriptions of it across some other articles. Punycode uses a numeral system the authors called "generalized variable-length integers" (is that term well-known in maths in general?) to encode a sequence of integers in a bijective way. My question is about why the authors decided to use this mixed-radix system. In particular, I don't understand how they choose appropriate thresholds for each digit.

> These `t(j)` values cause the representation to favor integers within a particular range determined by the bias.

`t(j)` is the threshold for the `j`th digit, it is calculated as  `t(j) = base * (j + 1) - bias`, and is used to calculate the weights of each digit: `w(j) = w(j-1) * (base - t(j-1))`, except for the first digit which has a weight of 1.

The bias is set per-number (not per-digit), and is based on the previous number in the sequence, because the authors assume that consecutive numbers are likely to be of the same order of magnitude:

> The parameters of this integer representation are dynamically adjusted using "bias adaptation", to improve efficiency when consecutive deltas have similar magnitudes.

A delta is just one of the numbers in the sequence of "generalized variable-length integer" encoded in Punycode. The delta itself encodes a unicode character and that character's index in the string. The unicode character is selected by the quotient of the delta divided by the length of the decoded string so far, and the index of the character is the remainder of that division. Why is it a good assumption that consecutive deltas will have similar magnitudes?

I understand that it would be maximally efficient per-number to represent each number in the largest possible base, given the number of available digits; Punycode uses 36 digits, so they could simply represent each number in base-36. In this case though, they may lose efficiency overall because they would have to insert non-digit delimiters between each number. But it's not obvious to me why this method would definitely be less efficient overall, because Punycode's method doesn't use the largest-possible base for each digit (it uses `36 - t(j - 1)`), so some numbers may have fewer digits in base-36 than in their generalized variable-length integer representation.

How is it guaranteed that the sequence of thresholds will allow all of the remaining digits of this number to pass, but will detect the least significant digit of the next number?

Comment: I also wonder, has Punycode's numeral system been proven to be the most efficient way to represent a sequence of _n_ integers with _k_ symbols?